# Listbox event after barcode scanning

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using listbox in window application, my listbox have some number of barcodes.

I want to scan them by barcode reader and then want to move them in another listbox, but I am not able to find any event of listbox which automatically fires and move barcodes to another listbox.

Comment: Why would there be such an event?

Comment: How does the listbox know when a barcode has been scanned? You could raise an event when a barcode is successfully read, but that assumes that your program also controls the barcode scanner.

Comment: Some barcode scanners emulate keyboards and others can be fully integrated into your program and provide decent API's. These API's will generally contain an event for when a code is successfully read, so check your documentation if you're using a scanner like this. If it a keyboard emulator then check the "keys" pressed, as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with my scanner if the ListBox has focus:

```
string scannerInput = "";

private void listBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((int)e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(scannerInput );
        scannerInput = "";
    }
    else scannerInput += e.KeyChar.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @JamesCrawshaw, yes you was right  keypress/keydown event is calling on the Listbox after scanning, but I am facing one problem, from above code I am getting only one char of scanned barcode input because my barcode scanner is giving one by one char of barcode, like if barcode is 3345-0000-001 then on scanning this barcode keypress event called and I get only one char but I want whole string '3345-0000-001' on scanning, can you please help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: First you should try to test the behaviour by letting it send its output to, say, NotePad. If it sends all the characters to NotePad in __one__ line it will work in you app as well. If not, please report __what__ it does!

Comment: Actually scanner is giving one char on first time scanning and then second.. so on.. but KeyPress event only call first time and only receive one char from scanner. How will I get whole string of barcode from scanner in first time.

Comment: Forget the listbox for the time being and test it in notepad!!

Comment: @Neeraj: Have you perhaps __moved__ the variable `scannerInput` __into__ the `KeyPress` event?`?

Comment: Just use the code in my answer! Note how the variable is sitting outside the event!

Answer (score 1):

Most Barcode scanners adds a "carrier return", I.e. <kbd>Enter</kbd> after reading the barcode.

Like simulating a press of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You could try and catch this <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keypress/keydown event on the form or listbox control (If the listbox is in focus)

Comment: Assuming that the listbox is in focus at the point of scanning.

Comment: @JamesCrawshaw , yes, as stated in my answer :-)

Comment: Whoops... sorry. I should really read the whole answer first!

Answer (score 0):

Having a single control handle a barcode scan from a keyboard wedge is problematic.  Requiring a user to set focus to a control before scanning is asking for trouble.  Try having the form handle the scanning by implementing the “PreviewTextInput” event.

Most Keyboard wedge scanners can be programmed to send a preamble and post amble codes.  These should be unprintable ASCII characters.  I’ve used Char(2) and Char(3).  They are STX – Start of text and ETX – End of text respectively.

```
bool InteceptBarcode = false;
string barcodeValue = string.empty;
private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if(InteceptBarcode)
    {
        barcodeValue = += e.Text
        e.Handled = true; //The keyboard character will stop bubbling up the control tree 
    }
    else if (e.Text == (char)2  //Start of text character
    {
        InterceptBarcode = true;
        barcodeValue = string.empty;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Text == {char)3) //End of text character
    {
            InterceptBarcode = false
        e.Handled = true;
        //Now do what ever you need to do on the UI.
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }                   
}
```